# How to change the sitemap for system administrator role in crm 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I have created role based sitemap depending upon the user.
When the user other than system administrator logs in to the system it works fine but when the system administrator logs in it shows duplicate menu as I have created different subarea inside area in xml sitemap.

does anyone have faced this issue.
any help on this will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Since you cannot limit system admin rights I am not aware of any way to hide sitemap elements from an administrator.  Do you actually need separate menus or could you just show/hide elements within a single menu?

Comment: Thanks, actually I just want to hide the duplicate menus which are visible to administrator.